# Selector connected to multiple components, is parent component guaranteed to update first?

Tags: reactjs, reselect

I have my components Parent and Child as below:

```
const Parent = ({ valueFromSelector }) => {
  if (valueFromSelector === undefined) return null;

  return <Child />;
}
```

```
const Child = ({ valueFromSelector }) => {
  return <span>`i am unsafely using ${valueFromSelector.property}`</span>
}
```

Is the usage of `valueFromSelector.property` unsafe, or can I be sure that Child never will update/render if since `valueFromSelector` is safeguarded in Parent?

Basically what I'm asking is if selectors are guaranteed to update in "order" from parent components to child components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, unfortunately, selectors are not guaranteed to update in "order" from parent components to child components. Issues are possible under certain conditions.

The issue is called zombie children, and the redux version 6 was an attempt at fixing the issue, but unfortunately the Context API was unable to support redux fully in terms of performance. So they had to revert that change in version 7, and there was no way to prevent the issues for function components.

Here are some articles that answers your question in more detail:

https://kaihao.dev/posts/Stale-props-and-zombie-children-in-Redux

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#stale-props-and-zombie-children